# mount defaults and various filesystems

Tags: mount, fstab, options

I read on the man page

`defaults
Use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, async, and relatime.`

Do the options set depend on a mounted filesystem or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount), `defaults` is listed under `Filesystem Independent Mount Options`, which means it doesn't depend on the filesystem type.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, didn't notice it

Comment: Now you do, no need to be sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you mean by "depend on the mounted file system" ?

To begin with, this line in the man page defines an option called `defaults`. This option `defaults` is available for all file systems as indicated by the section heading. It stands exactly for the set of options listed in the definition of `defaults`. You may see it as a replacement for that list.

Then, a default option may be surperseded by other considerations.
For example, if you use the option `default` for a DVD drive, you will end up with option `ro` rather than `rw` when the drive is mounted because DVDs have read-only file systems (the file system does not exists yet when you write). A file containing the image of an ISO 9660 file system will also be mounted `ro` with a loop device.
I do not know for an ext4 file system image (I still have to try it).

Also, if you use `default` and follow it with other options, it may cancel some of the options set by `default`. For example the option `owner` will cancel many.